# Email function not working

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo

I am not able to get the email to send out for some reason it is not grabbing the users lanId. Not sure what I am doing wrong. I have been trying to figure out why the lanID is not posting or is there another way of writing the email function.

```
//update proccess 
<?php

$serverName = "localhost";
try{
$db= new PDO( "sqlsrv:server=$serverName ; Database=systems_requests", "test", "test");
$db->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );

$sql = 'UPDATE requests Set name= :name, lanId= :lanId,  department= :department,manager= :manager,request= :request,request_comments= :request_comments,status= :status,comments= :comments,compUser= :compUser, compDt= :compDt WHERE id= :id';
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);  
$stmt->bindParam(':id', $_POST['id'], PDO::PARAM_INT);       
$stmt->bindParam(':lanId', $_POST['lanId'], PDO::PARAM_STR);       
$stmt->bindParam(':name', $_POST['name'], PDO::PARAM_STR); 
$stmt->bindParam(':department', $_POST['department'], PDO::PARAM_STR);   
$stmt->bindParam(':manager', $_POST['manager'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':request', $_POST['request'], PDO::PARAM_STR);    
$stmt->bindParam(':request_comments', $_POST['request_comments'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':status', $_POST['status'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':comments', $_POST['comments'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':compUser', $_POST['compUser'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':compDt', $_POST['compDt'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->execute();





$to = $_POST['lanId'] . "@exchange.test.com";
$subject = "Request";
$headers = "From: test@test.com";  

$message ="LanID: " . $_POST['lanId'] . " 


" ."User Name: ".  $_POST['name'] ." 

". "Department: " . $_POST['department'] . " 

" ."Manager: ".  $_POST['manager'] . " 

". "User Request: " . $_POST['request'] . "

" ."User Request comments: ".  $_POST['request_comments'].  "

" ."Status: " .  $_POST['status'] .  " 

" ."Systems comments: ".  $_POST['comments'] .  " 

" ."Completed by: ".  $_POST['compUser'] ;

mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers); 
}catch(PDOException $exception){ 
            echo "Error: " . $exception->getMessage();
    }   
?>
```

update.php

```
 //start of form to select the id to update 
    <?php
        include('db_connect.php');
        $id=$_GET['id'];
        $result = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM requests WHERE id= :id");
        $result->bindParam(':id', $id);
        $result->execute();
        for($i=0; $row = $result->fetch(); $i++){
    ?>

    <html>
    <head>
    <title></title>

    <style type="text/css">

    }
    .body{
        background-color: #F2F2F2;
        border: thin solid #666666;
    }
    </style>

    </head>
    <body class='body'>
    <form action = "update_process.php"  method ="post" class="Form">

    <p><input type ="hidden" name = "id" value="<?php print($id); ?>"</p>

    <h2 align="center">Users request  Information</h2>
    <table border='1' align="center">
    <tr>    
        <td>LAN ID:</td>
    <td><input type="text" value ="<?php  print($row['lanId']) ?>"name="lanId"></td>

        <td>Name:</td>
    <td><input type="text" value ="<?php  print($row['name']) ?>"name="name"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>    
        <td>Department Location</td>
    <td><input type="text" value ="<?php  print($row['department']) ?>"name="department"></td>

        <td>Manager</td>
    <td><input type="text" value ="<?php  print($row['manager']) ?>"name="manager"></td>
    </tr>


    <tr>    
        <td>Request</td>
    <td><input type="text" value ="<?php  print($row['request']) ?>"name="request"></td>

    <td></td>
    <td></td>

    </tr>
    </table>
    <h2 align='center'>Requested Comments</h2>
    <table border='1' align="center">


    <tr>    

    <td width='400'  height="40">
    <textarea name="request_comments"  style="width: 600px; height: 81px" style="text-transform:uppercase ;"><?php echo $row['request_comments']; ?></textarea></td>

    </tr>

    </table>


    <h2 align="center">Complete or Update Requests Status</h2>

    <table border='1' align="center" style="width: 595px">
    <tr>    
        <td>Completed Date</td>
    <td style="width: 303px">
    <input type="text" value ="<?php echo date("m/d/Y",time())?>"name="compDt" style="width: 148px"></td>


    </tr>
    <tr>    
        <td>Status</td>
    <td style="width: 303px"><select name ="status" style="width: 149px" >
    <option value <?php if ($row['status']==1){ print('selected');}  ?> ="Received">Received</option>
    <option value <?php if ($row['status']==2){ print('selected');}  ?> ="Completed">Completed</option>
    <option value <?php if ($row['status']==3){ print('selected');}  ?> ="Cancelled">Cancelled</option>
    <option value <?php if ($row['status']==4){ print('selected');}  ?> ="In_Progress">In_Progress</option>
    <option value <?php if ($row['status']==5){ print('selected');}  ?> ="On_Hold">On_Hold</option>

    </select>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Completed by</td>
    <td style="width: 303px"><select name ="compUser" style="width: 149px" >
    <option value <?php if ($row['compUser']==1){ print('selected');}  ?> ="">Please Select....</option>
    <option value <?php if ($row['compUser']==1){ print('selected');}  ?> ="xgrh">xgrh</option>
    <option value <?php if ($row['compUser']==2){ print('selected');}  ?> ="zeap">zeap</option>
    <option value <?php if ($row['compUser']==2){ print('selected');}  ?> ="xjae">xjae</option>
    <option value <?php if ($row['compUser']==5){ print('selected');}  ?> ="zmoj">zmoj</option>
    </select>
    </td>
    </tr>


    </table>
    <div align='center'>    
    <br>Systems Support Comments:<br>   
    <textarea name="comments" Value = "<?php  print($row['request_comments']) ?>"  style="width: 593px; height: 90px"></textarea><br>
        <br>

    <input type="submit" value= "Update Information">
    <br>
    </div>
    </form>


    </body>
    </html>
    <?php
        }
    ?>
```

Comment: echo the "$_POST['lanId']" and see if you get anything.

Comment: are you getting other fields from $_POST, such as the name, dept, mgr?

Comment: I tried that and got nothing on the screen

Comment: The record updates no issue just does not send email

Comment: The mail has been sent, but just without `lanId`?
Do you have other errors in your script - enable [error_reporting](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) first.

Comment: Also check, if the mail-server is correctly configured, if there are no sent emails.

Comment: here is a better idea, do a print_r($_POST) see if you get anything. @timmy made a good point, do you have display_errors to On? on your pnp.ini file? after you modify that restart apache

Comment: have you installed sendmail?

Comment: `if(mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers)){ echo "Success";} else{ echo "Error";}` - if mail isn't going out at all, then add error reporting.

Comment: mail server works my insert is sending out emails with no issues

Comment: it says error on my page Fred-ii

Comment: it is posting the lanId and all the records not sure why it keeps saying this error [26-Nov-2014 07:57:42 America/Los_Angeles] PHP Warning:  mail(): SMTP server response: 501 5.1.3 Invalid address in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Systems\update_process.php on line 52

Comment: If it says error, then mail didn't go out. Are you checking your logs including adding error reporting?

Comment: that error indicates to me that it is not grabbing the lanId correctly or posting the lanId to the email function correctly

Comment: I get a success when I manually input the user lanId

Comment: Ok, try this. `$mailout = mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);` then do a `var_dump($mailout);` see what's being passed through. Obviously, it's the id that's not being populated, so you'll need to find out why.

Comment: Also try `var_dump($_POST);` to see which values are passed through the php file.  
Another question: What's the name of the php file and is it in the same directory as the html form?

Comment: trying to figure a way to get the lanId to post into the $to

Comment: Just a hunch. I can't spend anymore time because I've got jobs coming in. Try `$to = $_GET['lanId'] . "@exchange.test.com";` since you are doing `$id=$_GET['id'];` or just `$to = $id . "@exchange.test.com";`

Comment: Thanks that didn't work But I will keep trying to figure it out

Comment: If you find that you are receiving 5.1.x errors while trying to send
SMTP emails it may be that your mail server has either the parameter
strict_rfc821_envelopes = yes or adheres strictly to the ESMTP (RFC
5321) protocols which require email addresses to be enclosed in < > as
in "John Doe <j...@email.com>".

Comment: You can also try using sessions and assign a session variable to the id, something's getting lost somewhere. Now, if you say that your update works, but mail's not being sent, that part is equally baffling me. What did `var_dump` reveal?

Comment: var dump revealed the record information in an array and everything was there. The lanId @exchange.test.com suppose to send email out because when I put in the lanId manually like xgrh@exchange.test.com it works email is sent out. some reason $to = &_POST['lanId']. "exchange.test.com"; is not pulling xgrh into that field

Comment: How would i do a session that might work

Comment: Not 100% sure, but try `$_GET['lanId'] = $_SESSION['lanId'];` placed under `$id=$_GET['id'];` then `$to = $_SESSION['lanId'] . "@exchange.test.com";` while loading `session_start();` inside all pages.

Comment: It is saying Undefined Variable for $_GET['lanId'] = $_SESSION['lanId'];

Comment: my session says null

Comment: Figured it out was a space I created a variable and used trim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I  added a variable and trim around it. now it works. I will be doing the same to everyone of them.

```
 <?php

    $serverName = "localhost";
    try{
    $db= new PDO( "sqlsrv:server=$serverName ; Database=systems_requests", "test", "test");
    $db->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );

  $lanId=trim($_POST['lanId']);

    $sql = 'UPDATE requests Set name= :name, lanId= :lanId,  department= :department,manager= :manager,request= :request,request_comments= :request_comments,status= :status,comments= :comments,compUser= :compUser, compDt= :compDt WHERE id= :id';
    $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);  
    $stmt->bindParam(':id', $_POST['id'], PDO::PARAM_INT);       
   $stmt->bindParam(':lanId',  $lanId, PDO::PARAM_STR);     
    $stmt->bindParam(':name', $_POST['name'], PDO::PARAM_STR); 
    $stmt->bindParam(':department', $_POST['department'], PDO::PARAM_STR);   
    $stmt->bindParam(':manager', $_POST['manager'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(':request', $_POST['request'], PDO::PARAM_STR);    
    $stmt->bindParam(':request_comments', $_POST['request_comments'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(':status', $_POST['status'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(':comments', $_POST['comments'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(':compUser', $_POST['compUser'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(':compDt', $_POST['compDt'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->execute();





  $to =   $lanId."@exchange.test.com";
    $subject = "Request";
    $headers = "From: test@test.com";  

$message ="LanID: "  .   $lanId . " 


    " ."User Name: ".  $_POST['name'] ." 

    ". "Department: " . $_POST['department'] . " 

    " ."Manager: ".  $_POST['manager'] . " 

    ". "User Request: " . $_POST['request'] . "

    " ."User Request comments: ".  $_POST['request_comments'].  "

    " ."Status: " .  $_POST['status'] .  " 

    " ."Systems comments: ".  $_POST['comments'] .  " 

    " ."Completed by: ".  $_POST['compUser'] ;

    mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers); 
    }catch(PDOException $exception){ 
                echo "Error: " . $exception->getMessage();
        }   
    ?>
```

Comment: This doesn't male sense. Look at the PHP documentation of trim(). It only strips whitespaces from the beginning and the end of a string. So if the `lanId` is empty, it should be empty after the function call, too. I don't think that this is the suitable solution for this problem and it maybe only works, because of a side effect. :/